# Почему я получаю эту ошибку? (BLAZOR C #)

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

Я попытался запустить следующий компонент и получил ошибку, которая сбрасывает все мое программное обеспечение:

#### C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\chat\chat\Shared\Component.razor

```
<h1>encrypted chat</h1>
<EditForm  Model="@_Encrypted">
    <InputText id="user" @bind-Value="@_Encrypted.user"></InputText>
<input id="pass" type="password" @bind-value="@_Encrypted.pass" />
    <InputText id="subject" @bind-Value="@_Encrypted.subject"></InputText>
    <InputText id="message" @bind-Value="@_Encrypted.msg" />

    <button type="submit"  @onclick="@_Encrypted.sendmsg">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    public irc_encrypted _Encrypted = new irc_encrypted();
   // public Webs webs = new Webs();

}
}
```

И я попытался решить это сам и получил следующую ошибку:

> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'EventCallback'

Обратите внимание, что программное обеспечение представляет собой программное обеспечение для чата, основанное на протоколе BitMessage (ссылка на запись в русской Википедии, которая касается программного обеспечения и протокола: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmessage).

Comment: у вас одна открывающая скобка в коде `{` и две закрывающие `}}`.

Comment: где именно?? я не могу найти

Comment: в коде в вашем вопросе

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308947/blazor-cannot-convert-from-method-group-to-eventcallback